# Error when FFT a filter/whitenoise

Tags: signal-processing, scilab

Trying to do a spectral estimation but have a problem I'm not sure what the reason is, I'm also following this documentation as well https://www.scilab.org/product/man/pspect.html

I am trying to first get the fft of the filter with the white noise, my filter being a band pass

```
Fs=22050;
cf=[650 750]/Fs;
rand('normal');rand('seed',0);
x=rand(1:1024-33+1);
hn=iir(4,'bp','butt',cf,[0 0]);
h1=[hn 0*ones(1:max(size(x))-1)];
x1=[x 0*ones(1:max(size(hn))-1)];
hf=fft(h1,-1);
```

Problem comes when i try to do the fft, scilab tells me

```
--> hf=fft(h1,-1);
in builtin                fftw 
Function not defined for given argument type(s),
  check arguments or define function %r_fftw for overloading.
```

I am not sure what the problem could be other than something is wrong with my filter but even then I am not aware what could be wrong, used it to filter some signal and it worked well.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply the Fourier transform to a filter. The filter is represented by a rational polynomial function in the Laplace s-domain, and the Fourier transform takes in a function in the time domain as argument. As of the `fft()`, it should be applied to a matrix containing the samples of your signal. If you want to see the behaviour of your filter over white noise, you should pass the signal to the filter, and use `fft()` afterwards.

As for your code, `iir()` returns the typed listed `hn` containing a rational polynomial, which is the filter's transfer function. When you do

```
h1=[hn 0*ones(1:max(size(x))-1)];
```

you create a row matrix `h1` in which the first element is the filter's transfer function. The second part `0*ones(1:max(size(x))-1)` simply creates a row matrix made of 991 zeros and append it to the first element. Since all elements in a matrix have to be of the same type, all these zeros become rational null polynomials. Such matrix is not acceptable as an input to `fft()`.

If you want to quickly check if your filter works the way it is supposed to, instead of manually testing it with white noise, you could try using `bode(hn)` to create a [Bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot), in which you can check its cut-off frequencies, amplitude responses and phase shifts.